# Installation limit on purchased themes for Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, theme, license

Is there a limit on the number of stores or sites on which a purchased Magento 2 theme can be installed?

Comment: it depends on the theme's license if it is allowed for multiple websites then its okay. it depends on their side only.